# How do I multiply dictionary elements and get a sum

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
flow = {('I0','O0'): 2, 
        ('I0','O1'): 3, 
        ('I0','O2'): 2, 
        ('I0','O3'): 3, 
        ('I1','O0'): 2, 
        ('I1','O1'): 1, 
        ('I1','O2'): 4, 
        ('I1','O3'): 2, 
        ('I2','O0'): 3, 
        ('I2','O1'): 4, 
        ('I2','O2'): 2, 
        ('I2','O3'): 1,
        ('I3','O0'): 3, 
        ('I3','O1'): 2, 
        ('I3','O2'): 2, 
        ('I3','O3'): 4
}

x=[1,3]
            
cost_of_assignment= flow(('Ix','O0')*0+('Ix','O1')*1+('Ix','02')*2+('Ix','03')*3)
```

how to write a loop so that it cycles through values of `x` from 1-3. I've tried the algo I wrote above and the error it gives me:

> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
You need to repeat your tutorial lessons on how to iterate through a list of values.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're looking for, but you could do something like this:

```
for lhs in ('I0', 'I1', 'I2', 'I3'):
  print(flow[(lhs, 'O0')] * 0 + 
        flow[(lhs, 'O1')] * 1 + 
        flow[(lhs, 'O2')] * 2 +
        flow[(lhs, 'O3')] * 3)
```

Which outputs:

```
16
15
11
18
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an odd requirement, but `eval` should get what you want:

```
flow = {('I0','O0'): 2, 
        ('I0','O1'): 3, 
        ('I0','O2'): 2, 
        ('I0','O3'): 3, 
        ('I1','O0'): 2, 
        ('I1','O1'): 1, 
        ('I1','O2'): 4, 
        ('I1','O3'): 2, 
        ('I2','O0'): 3, 
        ('I2','O1'): 4, 
        ('I2','O2'): 2, 
        ('I2','O3'): 1,
        ('I3','O0'): 3, 
        ('I3','O1'): 2, 
        ('I3','O2'): 2, 
        ('I3','O3'): 4
}

costlst = [eval("flow[('I"+str(x)+"', 'O0')]*0+flow[('I"+str(x)+"', 'O1')]*1+flow[('I"+str(x)+"', 'O2')]*2+flow[('I"+str(x)+"', 'O3')]*3") for x in [0,1,2,3]]

print(costlst)
```

Output

```
[16, 15, 11, 18]
```